# Use of colon operator ':' in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why

```
asdf:'qwer'
```

returns `qwer`, but

```
var a = asdf: 'qwer';
```

returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` ?

Comment: What do you think `var a = asdf: 'qwer';` is meant to do?

Comment: Friendly speaking I don't know why asdf:'qwer' doesn't return syntax error.

Comment: what you want to do?please be specific

Comment: I knew about ternary operators. This code was added accidentally before  return{zxcv:'cvbn'} and I wonder why browser doesn't return syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no colon operator in Javascript (except as part of the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?:`).

In your first snippet, `asdf:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). In your second one, it's a syntax error, because labels are only valid before statements, not inside expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Because it can be used as a label. You can tag for example a loop so you can easily break a superior one, but it has to be a separate command:

```
MAIN:
while (a) {
  while (b) {
    break MAIN;
  }
}
```

But obviously you can add a label to anything even if it's useless.